# HDF5Cpp Extending Compound Dataset Hyperslab problem

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have a simple program that extends an struct of two ints. The structure seems ok However when I'm writing the second struct to the extended memory it overwrites the first structs data and the extended data is just garbage. Any one have any idea where I'm going wrong? I think it's in the memory setup.
Any help greatly appreciated,

'''

```
typedef struct s1_t {
    int    a;
    int    b;
} s1_t;


int main(void)
{
    hid_t           file, space, dset, dcpl, filetype;    /* Handles */
    herr_t          status;
      
   

    s1_t s1;

    s1.a = 19;
    s1.b = 67;

   
    //Create a new file using the default properties.
    file = H5Fcreate(FILE, H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);

    //Create compound datatype
    filetype = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(s1_t));
    H5Tinsert(filetype, "a", HOFFSET(s1_t, a), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    H5Tinsert(filetype, "b", HOFFSET(s1_t, b), H5T_NATIVE_INT);
    

    const hsize_t ndims = 1;
    const hsize_t ncols = 1;

    hsize_t dims[ndims] = { 1 };
    hsize_t max_dims[ndims] = { H5S_UNLIMITED };
    hid_t file_space = H5Screate_simple(ndims, dims, max_dims);
    std::cout << "- Dataspace created" << std::endl;


    hid_t plist = H5Pcreate(H5P_DATASET_CREATE);
    H5Pset_layout(plist, H5D_CHUNKED);
    hsize_t chunk_dims[ndims] = { 1 };
    H5Pset_chunk(plist, ndims, chunk_dims);
    std::cout << "- Property list created" << std::endl;

    //Create the unlimited dataset.
    dset = H5Dcreate(file, DATASET, filetype, file_space, H5P_DEFAULT, plist, H5P_DEFAULT);
    std::cout << "- Dataset 'dset1' created " << dset<<std::endl;


    status = H5Dwrite(dset, filetype, H5S_ALL, file_space, H5P_DEFAULT, &s1);

    

   
    //read back the data, extend the dataset,
    //and write new data to the extended portions.

    //Open file and get the dataset
    H5::H5File* file2 = new H5::H5File(FILE, H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
   
    H5::DataSet* dataset = new H5::DataSet( file2->openDataSet(DATASET));
        
    //new data to add to the dataset
    s1_t s2;
    s2.a = 98;
    s2.b = 55;
 
        
    dims[0] = 2;
    //dims[1] = ncols;
    hid_t mem_space = H5Screate_simple(ndims, dims, NULL);
    std::cout << "- Memory dataspace created" << std::endl;
    H5Dset_extent(dset, dims);
    std::cout << "- Dataset extended" << std::endl;
    
    file_space = H5Dget_space(dset);
    hsize_t start[2] = { 0, 0 };// Start of hyperslab
    hsize_t count[2] = { 2, ncols };// Block count
    
    H5Sselect_hyperslab(file_space, H5S_SELECT_SET, start, NULL, count, NULL);
    std::cout << "- First hyperslab selected" << std::endl;
    H5Dwrite(dset, filetype, mem_space, file_space, H5P_DEFAULT, &s2);
    std::cout << "- First buffer written" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}   '''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a particular library, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it may alleviate you from HDF5 low-level details.

Your use-case could be solved as follows using this library in C++ (i.e. create an extendible dataset and populate it, row by row, without erasing already stored data):

```cpp
#include "HDFql.hpp"

typedef struct s1_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
}s1_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // declare variables
    s1_t s1;
    char script[1024];
    int number;

    // create an HDF5 file named 'example.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
    HDFql::execute("CREATE AND USE FILE example.h5");

    // create a dataset named 'dset' of data type compound composed of two members named 'a' and 'b'. The dataset starts
    // with one row and can grow (i.e. be extended) in an unlimited fashion
    sprintf(script, "CREATE DATASET dset AS COMPOUND(a AS INT OFFSET %d, b AS INT OFFSET %d)(UNLIMITED)", offsetof(s1_t, a), offsetof(s1_t, b));
    HDFql::execute(script);

    // register variable 's1' for subsequent use (by HDFql)
    number = HDFql::variableRegister(&s1);

    // populate variable 's1' with certain values
    s1.a = 19;
    s1.b = 67;

    // insert (i.e. write) data from variable 's1' into the last row of dataset 'dset' (thanks to a point selection)
    sprintf(script, "INSERT INTO dset[-1] VALUES FROM MEMORY %d", number);
    HDFql::execute(script);

    // alter (i.e. change) dimension of dataset 'dset' to +1 (i.e. add a new row at the end of 'dset')
    HDFql::execute("ALTER DIMENSION dset TO +1");

    // populate variable 's1' with certain values
    s1.a = 98;
    s1.b = 55;

    // insert (i.e. write) data from variable 's1' into the last row of dataset 'dset' (thanks to a point selection)
    sprintf(script, "INSERT INTO dset[-1] VALUES FROM MEMORY %d", number);
    HDFql::execute(script);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

For additional information, please take a look at HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) and check some examples on how to use it [here](http://www.hdfql.com/examples).